# How to change Nuxt meta without hid?

Tags: metadata, nuxt.js, meta

how I could change

```
<meta data-n-head="ssr" lang="en">
```

in the head.

Ive tried to add

```
{
  hid: 'lang',
  lang: 'ru'
},
```

And

```
{
  lang: 'ru'
},
```

but vue-meta create duplicate(

Comment: Shouldn't `lang` be part of `html`

Comment: i understand, but vue meta built-in nuxt creates it automaticly